# Collapsible group headers using md-virtual-repeat and md-virtual-repeat-container

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-material, infinite-scroll

I am trying to implement display collapsible groupings as a proof of concept using md-virtual-repeat and I am having problems to set height based on the inner content as with virtual-repeat items. I have created codepen example to illustrate the problem. Any solution based on CSS or angularJs will be greatly appreciated.

http://codepen.io/pyella/pen/XpXaEJ

**Edit 1:** I am trying this proof of concept to achieve infinite scrolling to render fixed dom elements as my list may contain really large number (10000 DOM elements to be rendered) which can cause performance and CPU issues and with this proof of concept anyone using angular to render huge data can use angular material and avoid performance issues.

**Note:** Please click on one of the years displayed to display the months-wrapper container. Currently height is hard coded to 250px and height of 100% doesn't display the months-wrapper container.

If the months-wrapper height is un commented it wouldn't show the months wrapper

```
.virtualRepeatdemoScrollTo #months-wrapper {
 /* height: 100%;*/
  /*position: initial;*/
}

.virtualRepeatdemoScrollTo .md-virtual-repeat-container {
  height: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted to achieve, but here is edited codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNBrJg

I added

```
.md-virtual-repeat-scroller{
  position: initial !important;
}
```

its previous `position` was `absolute` and that was the reason why its parent was not adjusting height.

I also removed `height: 100%` rule from `.virtualRepeatdemoScrollTo #vertical-container` selector.

Comment: Thanks for the reply patryK lucka, I am trying to achieve collapsible headers with groupings  for last twenty years and each grouping have set of months to be displayed. I am trying to have this proof of concept as virtual-repeat will only render fixed DOM elements( as my list is huge it was causing performance issues) . In your edited codepen we will not be seeing more than 5 years. I have updated my codepen example which shows all the years but now on click of year heading doesn't display the months below. Want achieve collapsible grouping heading from my codpen example.